# Securing Web API with Open ID Connect Access Token

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, openid-connect, pingfederate

I am searching for the right way to secure my rest api with open id connect. 
The rest api runs on a different web server.
The angular single page application based uses this [library](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) for getting the access token. 
The access token is a 'reference token' not a 'jwt'. Is there any middleware which I can use to access the user info endpoint to get the needed data from my identity provider or do I have to write my own one?

Identity Provider: Ping Federate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should introspect the token first, to get token claims.

Then lookup user info afterwards if needed, to get user info claims.

Out of interest there's an extensible design pattern I sometimes use [here](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/).